# Cypher - WHERE ANY intersection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'The Matrix'})-[:has_tag]->(movie1Tag:Tag)
WITH movie, collect(movie1Tag) AS movie1Tags
MATCH (movie2:Movie)-[:has_tag]->(movie2Tag:Tag)
WITH movie, movie1Tags, collect(movie2Tag) AS movie2Tags, movie2
WHERE ANY(movieTag IN movie1Tags 
                  WHERE movieTag IN movie2Tags) 
      AND NOT movie.name = movie2.name
RETURN DISTINCT movie2.name
```

Is there a way to return the intersections from the `WHERE ANY` statement? Is there a way to modify the query to return them?

Edit:
I got it working thanks to Anomaly211 answer. I also applied the intersections to the relationship using EXTRACT which I've included in below in case people are interested

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {name:'The Matrix'})-[:has_tag]->(movie1Tag:Tag) 
WITH movie, collect(movie1Tag) AS movie1Tags 
MATCH (movie2:Movie)-[:has_tag]->(movie2Tag:Tag) 
WITH movie, movie1Tags, collect(movie2Tag) AS movie2Tags, movie2 
WITH movie, movie1Tags, collect(movie2Tag) AS movie2Tags, movie2 FILTER(x IN movie1Tags WHERE x IN movie2Tags) AS intersect 
    FILTER(x IN movie1Tags WHERE x IN movie2Tags) AS intersect
WHERE ANY(movieTag IN movie1Tags WHERE movieTag IN movie2Tags) AND NOT movie.name = movie2.name AS intersect 
CREATE UNIQUE (movie)-[:share_tags {shared:EXTRACT(x IN intersect | x.identifier)}]->(movie2)
RETURN DISTINCT movie2.name, intersect
```

Comment: What do you mean by the intersection? How about an example?

Comment: Movie 1 has tags 'action','90s' 'fantasy' and 'science fiction'. Movie 2 has tags 'science fiction', '90s' and 'comedy'. So the intersection are tags 'science fiction' and '90s' - the tags they both share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the results and check for intersection.

```
 FILTER(x IN movie1Tags.name WHERE x IN movie2Tags.name)
```

This should give you only the tags that are present in both movie1tags and movie2tags

Comment: Excellent. I am glad you were able to get it working.

Comment: @Airomega - You may want to add your solution to your original question.

Comment: Good idea. Done :D